# How can I use a loop inside a react while appending formdata?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I guess this is a simple problem for those who are good in react. right now I have to do the frontend because we don't have any frontend dev now. I am facing an issue while passing the formdata. Here I have an array and I want to pass all the value from the array but I am able to pass just one index value.

like this

```
formData.append("payment", (payment[0].value));
```

but actually I want to pass the both the 0 and 1 index and append it in the formdata

```
formData.append("payment", (payment[0].value));
formData.append("payment", (payment[1].value));
```

I guess this is not the way because I didn't get a right output. Any help would be appreciated

```
const [payment, setPayment] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass one value to a given key,
So, if you want one key ("payment") to have a list of values, you can change your code to:

```
const valueList = payment.map(p => p.value);

formData.append("payment", JSON.stringify(valueList));
```

Comment: it is passing the data like ["COD", "Online"] but I want it like 
COD
Online 
Two different value